# Robot Framework: Check that Run Keyword If enters branches

Tags: robotframework

I have a keyword which contains several Run Keyword If branches, like:

```
main keyword with ${condition}
    Run Keyword If    ${condition}=="1"    keyword1
    Run Keyword If    ${condition}=="2"    keyword2
```

I'm looking for a mechanism to check that a branch gets executed.
I tried:

```
main keyword with ${condition}
    ${result1}=    Run Keyword If    ${condition}=="1"    keyword1
    ${result2}=    Run Keyword If    ${condition}=="2"    keyword2
    Should Be True    ${result1} is not None or ${result2} is not None
```

but I always get result1 and result2 None, even if keyword1 or keyword2 are executed.

Please give me a hint on this or how I could achieve my goal in a better way.

**LE:**
I tried out the second option suggested by Bence Kaulics.
My keywords now look like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
main keyword ${condition}
    ${result1} =     run keyword if  '${condition}'=='test_1'     run keyword and return status  keyword1
    ${result2} =     run keyword if  '${condition}'=='test_2'     run keyword and return status  keyword2
    should be true  ${result1} or ${result2}

keyword1
   log  "executed keyword1"

keyword2
    log  "executed keyword1"
```

And they work as expected. I get a fail in Robot if no branch is executed.

Thank you for the solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `keyword1` and `keyword2` probably do not have any return value, otherwise `${result1}` and `${result2}` should store the return values of your keywords.

So either add return values to your keywords:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${result1}=    Run Keyword If    1==1    Keyword1
    Log    Result1:${result1}
    
*** Keywords ***
Keyword1
    No Operation
    [return]    Anything can be returned
```

Output:

[image]

---

Or to have status results you can use the [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) like below. If you have keywords without return values this is the way to go.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${result1}=    Run Keyword If    1==1    Run Keyword And Return Status    Log    1
    ${result2}=    Run Keyword If    2==3    Run Keyword And Return Status    Log    2
    Log    Result1:${result1}
    Log    Result2:${result2}
```

This would give the following outputs:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply! My keyword1 and keyword2 are Python functions, but I still get result1 and result2 with value None even if my Python functions have return values.

Comment: I also tried your second suggestion, but I must be doing something wrong, because I get an error - I added details of it as LE to my original question.

Comment: @MonicaVoinescu     You have copied  `1` and `2` which were the arguments of the `Log` keyword I used, but your keyword takes no argument so you should delete those. You only need `${result1}=    Run Keyword If    1==1    Run Keyword And Return Status    keyword1` without the `1` at the end.

Comment: @MonicaVoinescu Share you Python function, it should work the same as any other keyword.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I removed the 1 and 2 and it works perfectly :)